# T- SQL Update Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two `Tables A` and  `Table B`

**Table A**

```
Date          Budget
9-1-2016        21
9-2-2016        10
```

**Table B**

```
Date          Amount      Budget
9-1-2016        12
9-1-2016        15
9-1-2016        17
9-2-2016        15
9-2-2016        10
9-3-2016        12
```

I want to divide the daily budget in **Table A** to the corresponding items in 
**Table B** as follows:

```
Date          Amount      Budget
9-1-2016        12          7
9-1-2016        15          7
9-1-2016        17          7
9-2-2016        15          5
9-2-2016        10          5
9-3-2016        12          0
```

For example, the budget of `9-1-2016` in **Table A** is divided into the 3 items in **Table B** which have the same date.

Comment: Based on what logic.....?  Your numbers don't make any sense.

Comment: The budget should spread for the same date from Table A to Table B.

Comment: So for the date (9-1-2016) in table A value of budget is 21.
I want this value to be equally divided in table B since there are three rows with that date. 

Does that make sense now ? I am happy to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

Note I've used a LEFT JOIN with table A, just to take care of nonexistent Budgets.

```
update tableB
set Budget = coalesce(a.Budget,0) / c.numB
from tableB b
     left join tableA a on a.Date = b.Date
     inner join (select Date, count(*) as numB
                 from tableB
                 group by date) c on c.Date = b.Date;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great.
Can you please provide an update statement

Comment: Wohoo. Thank yo so much